# What are some Best Camera Settings for Recording for Chroma Keying and which color of cloth reflects least green color?

Tags: after-effects, dslr, greenscreen, chromakey

I am recording footage for my music video and I am using chroma keying for eliminating the green screen and changing the background of my video. 
I am using **After Effects CC 14** video production/editing software. I don't have any third party plugin to remove the green screen background and so I am using **Keylight 1.2**. The steps that I am following for changing the background can be found in this [*tutorial*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baLLa_6zx14&t=6s).

My questions about the issues which I am getting here are as follows:

1. The main problem I am getting here is that when I am removing the background using Keylight 1.2, I am getting white light borders on the body of the subject. These borders keep coming after the edit even while I am recording the footage from even different cameras.
2. The second problem is, after creating the garbage matte and editing the clip at different levels as shown in the above-mentioned tutorial, some parts of the elbow of the subject/model are also becoming transparent. I cannot understand why.
3. Which color will be the best for my subject/model to wear during the shoot, so that it does not reflect the green color and will have the least reflection.
4. What will be some best camera settings for recording the footage in order to remove the green screen? My Camera is [***Nikon D5300***](https://www.amazon.in/Nikon-D5300-Digital-Camera-NIKKOR/dp/B00I4SGE0K) and the lens which I am using with it is [*18-55MM*](https://www.amazon.in/Nikon-Nikkor-18-55-3-5-5-6G-Camera/dp/B01AI8H58I/ref=sr_1_4?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1546871175&sr=1-4&keywords=18-55%20lens%20for%20nikon).

As an example, you may get my test videos [***here***](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1na5P7BpgFrYwnl18uF-h9pka92PHq8I3).

Comment: Welcome! What is your lighting setup? What kind of lights and where are they positioned? Can you share a sample already keyed in to show the problems? What changed that there is a color shift on the green screen between the first 2 and the third samples?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Sir, @MichaelLiebman. The lights are the normal ceiling LED Lights. They are positioned on the ceiling of the room. Second, The color shift occurred in the third footage because I changed the camera; i.e. I used my cellphone's camera for that one. Please help me ahead, Thanks in advance!!! :)

Comment: Thanks for showing interest in solving my problem Sir @MichaelLiebman . The answer to your queries:- **1st** :- I am using normal ceiling L.E.D Lights. They are positioned at the ceiling. I am not using any focus light right now. **2nd** :-  The color shift in the third sample with respect to the first and second samples, was due to the change of camera; i.e. I used my cellphone's camera for recording the third sample.
If your queries are satisfied, then please help further. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Improving your [lighting](https://nofilmschool.com/2014/12/advanced-lighting-tips-help-pull-perfect-croma-key) will vastly improve your chroma key more than any changes to camera settings. [This lighting design](http://lowel.tiffen.com/studioSetups/chromaset.html) can probably be adapted to use DIY fixtures.

Comment: @MichaelLiebman ok, thanks for the reference.  I'll read this article and will try to implement it. Also it'll be so great if you suggest me any cloth colour and type, for least reflection of green color. 

Answer (score 1):

Lighting is the biggest factor in improving this setup.  Move the subject further away from the sheet, use a lens that has a shallow depth of field so that any imperfections in the sheet are harder to see.  Light the sheet and the subject using diffuse lighting - large soft lights, or bright lights shone through large soft sheets, to make as few shadows as possible.  Backlight the subject slightly to get separation from the green screen and to reduce spill.

Camera-wise, use a camera which records as much colour depth as possible, and doesn't [subsample the colour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling).  (Don't know how the Nikon samples colour)

If you're using After Effects, [this is a very useful tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLaR8C1tcMg) to get a good clean key, but without doing the steps above, you may still have difficulty getting a good key.

Comment: All consumer-grade cameras use color subsampling, but less subsampling is better, that is, 4:4:4 > 4:2:2 > 4:2:0. Afaik, the Nikon 5300 does not have built-in waveform monitor, so I advise to take a photo of the backing, bring it into Photoshop and check the levels - ideally it should be thin horizontal line.

Comment: @RustyCore  thanks for the advice and the information. I'll search more about it on internet and understand what exactly you are trying to say as I'm a newbie and I couldn't understand some of your keywords. Thanks again 

Comment: @tomh thank you so much for your answer.  I'll try to understand it more clearly with some more research about the things you told me and will try to implement it. I will also watch the tutorial that you mentioned, thank you so much for that too. Yet I don't know much about subsampling of colors, but I will study on internet about it. I also don't have any good setup (if you had seen my embedded videos) to project a backlight (from screen to the back of the model). So, please may you help me in this issue also i.e. any DIY Ideas for it? p.s. Thanks again